# Desktop application with wonderful UI - Platform Decision

Tags: java, qt, user-interface, desktop-application

We have started to build a desktop application. The UI is ready on photoshop along with all the functionality decision's. On paper the UI looks stunning and we hope to replicate the same  inside the application.

Now the issue is: We are a team of 3 (2 developers + 1 designer). Building a separate application for Mac and Windows is just isn't feasible at all.

So the option is:

1. To do it on Java Swing. Saves time. But god! I will go crazy building it.
2. Use SWT or other toolkit. Tough to start, but can do if it can give the desired product.

Any other options?? Language no barrier (But the same code needs to function on both the platforms Mac and Windows). Product needs to be awesome

Comment: Why do you tag this with qt if you are planning to implement in java?

Comment: OP said that the language is not a barrier.

Comment: Are there "awesome" UIs written with Swing or SWT? Serious question, I haven't seen any so far.

Comment: @Fildor Qt has Java bindings.

Comment: Use Swing & give it an 'awesome' PLAF.

Comment: Whichever toolkit you use, you'll need some effort to make it look & feel native, and thus "awesome" on all platforms. There's more to native feel than the style of a button, it's the whole UI design that's different on each platform. So whether you go Swing, SWT, Qt or native, no toolkit will give you 100% awesomeness out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

There are people (including me) who actually managed to build Swing applications without going crazy :) The [Filthy Rich Clients](http://filthyrichclients.org/) book is a good start for creating "awesome" GUIs in Swing.

A newer alternative is JavaFX, which is supposed to be easier to use (I have no experience with it)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe QT? There is a project QT Jambi (http://qt-jambi.org/)